# Heroku Postgres Dump not creating Sequences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, import, heroku-postgres

Step1 Capture backup from Heroku

Step2 Download latest.dump from Heroku with Postgres 10.2 version

Step3 Exporting Heroku Dump in my Local Postgres 9.6.

Result: its import all data but not creating sequences in by Database which producing error on each creation query.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue as you, my database dumped from heroku has some missing db sequences... but not all of them, just a few.

Comment: Not yet just updated postgres version to use on local

Answer (score 0):

You can export a sequence using the following command

```
pg_dump -t your_sequence_name
```

If you're not sure how your sequences are named, try this command using `psql`

```
\d your_table_name
```

You might also want to take a look at [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-dumpall.html)

```
pg_dumpall > your_db.out
```